# How can I make the format document shortcut work for C source files in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

How can I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> work in a pure C file?
I really enjoy the auto formatting in C#, and I would like to have the same functionality in C as well.

I am using Visual Studio 2008, but it would probably be helpful if this worked in Visual Studio 2005 as well.

Comment: I really do not understand the -6 see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11851/whats-going-on-with-the-downvotes-on-rich-bs-questions

Comment: @Lucas: I don't believe you understand what rep is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2003, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> let you format a selection. This and other key combinations to format text can be found in menu *Edit* → *Advanced*.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010 and 2008 - 
the formatting of a selection can be achieved by CTRL+E CTRL+F..

I suppose since C/C++ can be peppered with loads of preprocessor directives and defines and such - formatting the entire document would be too difficult to process..